# How can i filter object value in angular 4 using ngModelChange?

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I'm trying to create a input field that filters the list geneated using ngFor, by "description" property name. The list is an object like this:

```
[
 { code: 001, description: "Product 001 description" },
 { code: 002, description: "Product 002 description" },
 { code: 003, description: "Product 003 description" },
 { code: 004, description: "Product 004 description" }
]
```

My function:

```
seachFilterData(e) {
    const query = e;
    this.filterData.map((items) => Object.values(items).forEach(value => {
      return Object.keys(value).filter(k => {
        if (value.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) {
          return items;
        }
      });
    }));
  }
```

the HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="tokenfield-search" placeholder="search" [ngModel]="searchFilter" value="" (ngModelChange)="seachFilterData($event)">
<div class="tokenfield-list">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let data of filterData | keys">
```

When i `console.log(items)` it's filtering, but the list doesnt change. Any thoughts?

Comment: try using an async pipe on filterData inside your ngFor. It will make filterData an observable watch for changes.

Comment: Tried using `async` like this: `*ngFor="let data of (filterData | keys) | async"` but i get an error. I also include the `import { AsyncPipe } from '@angular/common';`. The `keys`pipe i'm using is so that i can get prop.name and value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you only need to filter by description, you can do a compare with `indexOf` on just that field and filter out as needed.

```
seachFilterData(e) {
    const query = e;

    // convert to lowercase to do case insensitive search
    const query = e.toLowerCase();

    this.filterData = this.filterData.filter(item => item.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) !== -1);
}
```

If your query is `product 001`, your filtered list (`filterData`) will be

```
[
    { code: 001, description: "Product 001 description" }
]
```

Comment: Hi @LLai, this way works but, any way that i dont mutate the filterData, because when i remove a character on the input field, it doesnt bring back the full list.

Comment: @Takebo you can store a copy of the full list in another property. `this.data = // data from api; this.filterData = this.data.slice(0);` This will allow you to restore your list say when the `query = ""` Another solution would be to add another property to each object in your list, for example `isFiltered` then set that property to true or false depending on if its filtered. And within your ngFor show/hide the list item with the `[hidden]` directive

Comment: thank you! Created another variable to hold the initial state as you mentioned. Performance wise, which way do you think is better, cloning the object or adding a new property?

Comment: @Takebo I would say the new property when dealing with smaller list. I would think it would be more expensive to keep re-rendering the cloned list compared to just adding display: none through the [hidden] directive. When dealing with a larger data set, I would go with the cloned list + pagination. With most cases with the small list, the performance difference is probably negligible.

Comment: I guess with the larger data set (with pagination), its not so much a cloned list, but a slice of the full list.

Comment: i see, yes, went with cloning approch because there are more than 500k products registered. I might consider using both ways depending on the data size then. Thanks for taking your time! Helped me alot.

Comment: @Takebo glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

When you run `searchFilterData` you aren't saving the state.

```
seachFilterData(e) {
    const query = e;
    this.filterData = this.filterData.map((items) => {
      Object.values(items).forEach(value => {
      return Object.keys(value).filter(k => {
        if (value.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) {
          return items;
        }
      }});
    }));
  }
```

Comment: the filtered data will be an array of undefined values

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine can you put a stackblitz together so I can help you better?

Comment: @MikeTung, it gives me an error, saying cannot read property 'description' of undefined.

Comment: @Takebo your filter logic returns an array of undefines. I think your filter logic is too complex for what you need.